# не отображаются данные в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment, android-loader

Я пытаюсь следовать курсу от Udacity.Сейчас застрял на уроке 4С с Лоадерами,вроде бы делаю все,как там сказано,но результат не такой.При запуске приложения должны выводится данные о погоде в ListView,но вижу только пустой экран.Это фрагмент не добавился к активити,или листв'ю фрагмента пустое?
Вот класс MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer,mainFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

класс MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

   private static final int FORECAST_LOADER = 0;
    private ForecastAdapter mForecastAdapter;

    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOADER,null,this);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecast_fragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            updateWeather();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source and
        // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

mForecastAdapter = new ForecastAdapter(getActivity(),null,0);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);




        return rootView;
    }

    private void updateWeather() {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask(getActivity());

        String location = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
        weatherTask.execute(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateWeather();
    }


    @Override
    public android.content.Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String locationSetting = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
        String sortOrder = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC";
                Uri weatherForLocationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(
                                locationSetting, System.currentTimeMillis());

                        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                                weatherForLocationUri,
                                null,
                               null,
                                null,
                               sortOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {
mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

и класс FetchWeatherTask:

```
public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY ="85240dd016c5d1cb4e1badfb919aaae4" ;
    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();


    private final Context mContext;

    public FetchWeatherTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

    }

    private boolean DEBUG = true;




    /**
     * Helper method to handle insertion of a new location in the weather database.
     *
     * @param locationSetting The location string used to request updates from the server.
     * @param cityName A human-readable city name, e.g "Mountain View"
     * @param lat the latitude of the city
     * @param lon the longitude of the city
     * @return the row ID of the added location.
     */
    long addLocation(String locationSetting, String cityName, double lat, double lon) {
        long locationId;
        Cursor locationCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                WeatherContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID},
                WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING + " = ?",
                new String[]{locationSetting},
                null
        );
        if(locationCursor.moveToFirst()){
            int locationIdIndex = locationCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID);
            locationId = locationCursor.getLong(locationIdIndex);
        }
        else{
            ContentValues locationValues = new ContentValues();
            locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_CITY_NAME,cityName);
            locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING,locationSetting);
            locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT,lat);
            locationValues.put(WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG,lon);
        }
        return -1;
    }


    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr,
                                            String locationSetting)
            throws JSONException {

        // Now we have a String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format.
        // Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
        // into an Object hierarchy for us.

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.

        // Location information
        final String OWM_CITY = "city";
        final String OWM_CITY_NAME = "name";
        final String OWM_COORD = "coord";

        // Location coordinate
        final String OWM_LATITUDE = "lat";
        final String OWM_LONGITUDE = "lon";

        // Weather information.  Each day's forecast info is an element of the "list" array.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";

        final String OWM_PRESSURE = "pressure";
        final String OWM_HUMIDITY = "humidity";
        final String OWM_WINDSPEED = "speed";
        final String OWM_WIND_DIRECTION = "deg";

        // All temperatures are children of the "temp" object.
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";

        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";
        final String OWM_WEATHER_ID = "id";

        try {
            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            JSONObject cityJson = forecastJson.getJSONObject(OWM_CITY);
            String cityName = cityJson.getString(OWM_CITY_NAME);

            JSONObject cityCoord = cityJson.getJSONObject(OWM_COORD);
            double cityLatitude = cityCoord.getDouble(OWM_LATITUDE);
            double cityLongitude = cityCoord.getDouble(OWM_LONGITUDE);

            long locationId = addLocation(locationSetting, cityName, cityLatitude, cityLongitude);

            // Insert the new weather information into the database
            Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>(weatherArray.length());

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();

            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // These are the values that will be collected.
                long dateTime;
                double pressure;
                int humidity;
                double windSpeed;
                double windDirection;

                double high;
                double low;

                String description;
                int weatherId;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);

                pressure = dayForecast.getDouble(OWM_PRESSURE);
                humidity = dayForecast.getInt(OWM_HUMIDITY);
                windSpeed = dayForecast.getDouble(OWM_WINDSPEED);
                windDirection = dayForecast.getDouble(OWM_WIND_DIRECTION);

                // Description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                // That element also contains a weather code.
                JSONObject weatherObject =
                        dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);
                weatherId = weatherObject.getInt(OWM_WEATHER_ID);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                ContentValues weatherValues = new ContentValues();

                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOC_KEY, locationId);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE, dateTime);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_HUMIDITY, humidity);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_PRESSURE, pressure);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WIND_SPEED, windSpeed);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DEGREES, windDirection);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP, high);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP, low);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC, description);
                weatherValues.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID, weatherId);

                cVVector.add(weatherValues);
            }

            // add to database
            if ( cVVector.size() > 0 ) {
                ContentValues[] cvArray = new ContentValues[cVVector.size()];
                cVVector.toArray(cvArray);
                mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.CONTENT_URI,cvArray);
            }


            String sortOrder = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC";
            Uri weatherForLocationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(
                    locationSetting, System.currentTimeMillis());



            Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(weatherForLocationUri,
                    null, null, null, sortOrder);

            cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>(cur.getCount());
            if ( cur.moveToFirst() ) {
                do {
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                   DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues(cur, cv);
                    cVVector.add(cv);
               } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FetchWeatherTask Complete. " + cVVector.size() + " Inserted");




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        String locationQuery = params[0];

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int numDays = 14;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
            final String APPID_PARAM = "APPID";
            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM,OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY)
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }


        return null;
    }




}
```

Comment: Очень много лишнего кода. Фрагмент у вас добавился, а вот список, видать пуст. Возможно из-за того, что после выполнения задачи по скачиванию данных вы их или никуда не заносите или не добавляете в адаптер или не уведомляете адаптер о приходе новых данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. У класса `FetchWeatherTask` отсутствует метод `onPostExecute`
2. Вы делаете запрос, но явно не вызываете парсинг данных.
3. В метод `onPostExecute` нужно будет оповестить фрагмент, что вы записали данные.

То есть что вы сделали, это получили строку с сервера и все.

Comment: не,проблема была не в этом.Не знаю в чем точно,сейчас буду разбираться.Скопировал их FetchWeatherTask и вставил в свой,все заработало.Видно что то я не добавил и упустил.Проблема решена.

Comment: FetchWeatherTask у вас будет точно отличаться ;)

Comment: ну там проблема была не в onPostExecute.